# Why does Hendricks impersonate Wistrom in Dubai in MI: Ghost Protocol?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-ghost-protocol

Why was it important for the plot that Hendricks impersonates Wistrom in the codes exchange in Dubai? He could have done it by himself.

After the sandstorm he reveals to Ethan Hunt that he actually was Hendricks with a mask but it seems with lack of relevance for me.

Any reason that I didn't notice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is merely my personal opinion.

I think:

1. The transaction was too important for Hendricks so he had to do it himself instead of sending Wistrom or any other henchman.
2. Hendricks is wanted and a lot of people are looking for him for his extreme ideas including Ethan and his teammates. So he can't possibly travel from Russia to Dubai off the grid.

Thus, the disguise was the perfect solution for this. And who's better to impersonate than your right hand man Wistrom.

As why he revealed his identity to Ethan, I think to enjoy a moment of victory over him. And I haven't watched it for a while now but I think the mask was already half ripped off by the sand storm and the fight they had, so Ethan may already deduced that he was Hendricks.

Comment: I agree, you are right, without the mask he would have been identified by agent Sidorov at the entrance of Burj Khalifa, and Sidorov keeping the investigation over Hunt would have no reason, affecting the future plot where Sidorov is still chasing Hunt at Mumbai.